# How can I create a hourly use profile that computes aggregates based on the hour of day, day of week, in 1 hour, 2 hour and 3 hour windows in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, timescaledb

Hi I'm trying to create a usage profile, for each hour of the week from three months of data in Postgres.

The raw data is 90 days of `sensor_id, timestamp, value` and the table should have these columns:
`sensor_id, day_of_week, hour_of_day, avg_1hour, max_1hour, min_1hour, p95_1hour, max_2hour, avg_2hour min_2hour, p95_2hour, avg_3hour, max_3hour, min_3hour, p95_3hour`

The `*_1hour` columns are the result of aggregate functions for each `hour_of_day`, `day_of_week` pair over data within that hour. This is not so bad, and I believe this query generates the desired result.

```
   Select
     sensor_id,
     extract(dow from ts) as day_of_week,
     extract(hour from ts) as hour_of_day,
     avg(val) as avg_1hour,
     PERCENTILE_CONT(.95) within group (order by val) as p95_1hour,
     max(val) as max_1hour,
     min(val) as min_1hour
   from timeseries_data
   group by hour_of_day, day_of_week
   where ts between current_date - interval '1 day' and current_date - interval '91 day'
   order by day_of_week, hour_of_day asc
```

For example `avg_1hour` should have a row
where `day_of_week` is 1 (Monday) and `hour_of_day` would be 6 (5am), and then `avg_1hour` would be the average of every reading at Monday, 5am for the last 90 days.

The `*_2hour` and `*_3hour` columns are harder for me.

For the same day, hour pair on the `*_2hour` columns, for example there would be a row where  `day_of_week` is 1 (Monday), `hour_of_day` would be 6 (5am), but include the prior hour, so `avg_2hour` would be the average of `val`s from all rows where `day_of_week` is 1 (Monday), and `hour_of_day` would be 6 (5am) **or** 5 (4am).

`avg_3hour` would be the average of vals from all rows where `day_of_week` is 1 (Monday), and hour_of_day would be 6 (5am), 5 (4am) or 4 (3am).

This is running on a TimescaleDB server with Postgres 13.3.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you add a data sample and the exact expected results?

Comment: Hi! Approximately how many points do you have per sensor per hour? That'll help me formulate a better answer for you.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome, Gregory! Have you checked the [window function](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-window-function/)?

You can create window in different timeframes to project the groups.

Timescale also offers [counter-aggregations](https://docs.timescale.com/timescaledb/latest/how-to-guides/hyperfunctions/counter-aggregation/counter-aggs/#running-a-counter-aggregate-query-with-a-continuous-aggregate) that can be used with continuous aggregates to save aggregated data that can be reused in bigger timeframes without needing to recalculate everything.